# No permission when running a Google App Script from onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple google apps script that does something from the current Spreadsheet that I'm working on, and then transfers that data to another Spreadsheet just like below.

```js
function unplannedSubmit()
{
  //Some pre-requisite codes here//
  //Input is transferData, output is sending those data to a certain range in ds_main

  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL will be inserted here");
  var ds_main = ds.getSheetByName("Job Management - All");

  ds_main.getRange(1, 1, 5, 10).setValues(transferData);
}
```

For whatever reason, when I tried to run unplannedSubmit() manually, it runs perfectly fine. I made another code section to determine whether to run these functions or not, and I put them in the onEdit() function which supposedly runs whenever there is an edit to the active Spreadsheet

```js
function onEdit()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss_submitList = ss.getSheetByName("Jobsheet Change List / Request");
  var ss_unplanList = ss.getSheetByName("Unplanned Job List / Application");

  //Check for unplanned import function
  if (ss_unplanList.getRange("A1").getValue() > 0) unplannedSubmit();
}
```

But doing this only gives me this error:
[Error message on trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LXL8.png)

I tried to change my appscript.json file to this, but still doesn't work

```js
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

I also tried de-authorize and re-authorize the project to my google account, I tried changing the method from openByUrl to openById, but still can't figure out why I keep getting this error

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onEdit()` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs in a limited context that only has access to the current spreadsheet file. In that context, other spreadsheet files are not available.

To make it work, rename `onEdit()` to something like `onEditInstallable()` and run it through an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Note that the function will run *every* time you edit *any* value in the spreadsheet. You should include additional checks so that you only copy data between spreadsheet files when that *data* has changed.